# DataGridView GetCellDisplayRectangle too slow

Tags: c#, datagridview

I´m implementing function, that draws rectangle (just like in MS Excel) around selected cells in DGV. This function occurs on each `SelectionChanged` event and finds two diagonal cells from `SelectedCells` and draw `Rectangle` between them.

However method `GetCellDisplayRectangle(index,index,bool);` is realy slow it takes **~1300ticks**, and I´m calling it twice. Result is that selection Rectangle is renderend too slow and it doesn't look smooth.

So my question is, is there any other and faster way how to find X,Y,Height,Width of specific cell in DGV ?

Thank you
WH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Rectangle GetCellRectangle(int columnIndex, int rowIndex)
        {
            Rectangle selRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

            selRect.X = RowHeadersWidth + 1;
            for (int i = FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex; i < columnIndex; i++)
            {
                selRect.X += Columns[i].Width;
            }
            selRect.X -= FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnHiddenWidth;

            selRect.Y = ColumnHeadersHeight + 1;
            for (int i = FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex; i < rowIndex; i++)
            {
                selRect.Y += Rows[i].Height;
            }

            selRect.Width = Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Size.Width;
            selRect.Height = Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Size.Height;
            return selRect;
        }
```

This method return CellDisplayRectangle in aprox 8-10 ticks, insted of 1300.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height and the width of the cell using

```
cell.ContentBound.Width /*and */ cell.ContentBound.Height
```

These return the width and the height in int.

Else there is the Size attribute

```
cell.Size.Width /*and */ cell.Size.Height
```

Comment: Well I cant markt this as answer, because this way it's possible to find Width and Height of current cell, however you cant find this way X & Y of cell.

Comment: Location in form or in dgv?